# Kubuntu randomly freezes on new laptop after few hours of use

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, ssd, crash

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 14 G3 (AMD Ryzen 7 5700U, 16GB RAM), which is only a week old. It came with one 512GB NVMe SSD and Windows installed on it. I installed a second 500GB NVMe SSD and installed Kubuntu on that drive to have a dual boot system.

Everything seemed to be working fine, but after a few hours of use the Laptop randomly crashes in a weird way. First it starts behaving weird like I can't save or open files, the context menu of Dolphin or the Desktop has missing entries. Then after a few seconds some Icons start to disappear and finally the screen turns black and I only see my Mouse pointer.
I then have to hold down the power button until the Laptop shuts off and restart it, after which everything works fine until the next freeze in a few hours.
While it was slowly freezing I saw that Dolphin only showed my first SSD with Windows on it, but not the second with Linux on it. Maybe the second SSD is randomly disconnecting?

It happened both on battery and while plugged in, I also disabled secure boot in the UEFI but the error persists.

The last freeze was Jul 21st at 16:32 local time, I shut it down that minute and waited with the restart until 16:34, but my syslog only has entries after the restart, it does contain some weird characters that break this post tho, so here it is as a screenshot:

[Syslog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsS7F.png)

This is a snapshot of syslog around that time. Sadly I have no Idea how to troubleshoot this I don't know if there are any other logs that could be useful or any commands I could check my SSD with. I suspect the SSD with Kubuntu on it is randomly disconnecting and the system freezes up as it gradually tries to load stuff into RAM but I don't know how to go about validating and fixing this theory.

free -h :

```
    total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           13Gi       870Mi        12Gi        26Mi       582Mi        12Gi
Swap:         5,6Gi          0B       5,6Gi
```

vm-swapiness:

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog* is empty.

sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

```
GQCN20WW(V1.06)
```

grep -i sda /var/log/syslog* also empty.

grep -i sdb /var/log/syslog* :

```
Jul 15 23:38:33 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 15 23:38:33 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[986]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 15 23:38:33 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[986]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 15 23:47:48 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 15 23:47:48 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[812]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 15 23:47:48 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[812]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 15 23:47:48 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[812]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 15 23:49:26 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL PackageKit: in /7_acbedbed for update-packages package samba-dsdb-modules;2:4.13.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1;amd64;ubuntu-hirsute-updates-main was updating for uid 0
Jul 15 23:51:03 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL PackageKit: in /8_abdabedc for update-packages package samba-dsdb-modules;2:4.13.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1;amd64;ubuntu-hirsute-updates-main was installing for uid 0
Jul 15 23:51:03 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL PackageKit: in /8_abdabedc for update-packages package samba-dsdb-modules;2:4.13.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1;amd64;ubuntu-hirsute-updates-main was installing for uid 0
Jul 16 13:18:38 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 16 13:18:38 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[800]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 16 13:18:38 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[800]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 13:18:38 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[800]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 13:26:53 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 16 13:26:53 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[766]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 16 13:26:53 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[766]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 13:26:53 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[766]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 13:31:54 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 16 13:31:54 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[752]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 16 13:31:54 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[752]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 13:31:54 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[752]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 13:57:23 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 16 13:57:23 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[758]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 16 13:57:23 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[758]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 13:57:23 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[758]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 15:42:23 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 16 15:42:23 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[745]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 16 15:42:23 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[745]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 15:42:23 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[745]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 16:03:14 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 16 16:03:14 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[748]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 16 16:03:14 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[748]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 16:03:14 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[748]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 19:38:55 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 16 19:38:55 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[756]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 16 19:38:55 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[756]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 19:38:55 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[756]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 19:40:52 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 16 19:40:52 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[750]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 16 19:40:52 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[750]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 19:40:52 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[750]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 19:47:51 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 16 19:47:51 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[761]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 16 19:47:51 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[761]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 19:47:51 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[761]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 20:41:28 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 16 20:41:28 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[760]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 16 20:41:28 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[760]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 20:41:28 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[760]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 22:01:53 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 16 22:01:53 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[776]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 16 22:01:53 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[776]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 16 22:01:53 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[776]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 18 18:49:15 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 18 18:49:15 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[762]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 18 18:49:15 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[762]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 18 18:49:15 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[762]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 18 22:32:00 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 18 22:32:00 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[763]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 18 22:32:00 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[763]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 18 22:32:00 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[763]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 18 22:40:19 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 18 22:40:19 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[762]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 18 22:40:19 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[762]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 18 22:40:19 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[762]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 18 22:48:54 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 18 22:48:54 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[762]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 18 22:48:54 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[762]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 18 22:48:54 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[762]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 19 12:15:52 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 19 12:15:52 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[745]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 19 12:15:52 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[745]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 19 12:15:52 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[745]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 19 15:20:52 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 19 15:20:52 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[763]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 19 15:20:52 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[763]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 19 15:20:52 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[763]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 19 18:30:37 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 19 18:30:37 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[762]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 19 18:30:37 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[762]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 19 18:30:37 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[762]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 19 20:27:19 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 19 20:27:19 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[748]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 19 20:27:19 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[748]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 19 20:27:19 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[748]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 20 14:13:17 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL systemd[1]: Found device WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 EFI\x20system\x20partition.
Jul 20 14:13:17 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[748]: Device: /dev/nvme0, WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB
Jul 20 14:13:17 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[748]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state read from /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
Jul 20 14:13:17 rouben-ThinkBook-14-G3-ACL smartd[748]: Device: /dev/nvme0, state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.WDC_PC_SN530_SDBPMPZ_512G_1101-210248804767.nvme.state
grep: /var/log/syslog: binary file matches
```

grep -i nvme /var/log/syslog*
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GMT4BvQ7jX/

sudo lshw -C memory:

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: GQCN20WW(V1.06)
       date: 04/29/2021
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 22
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0,3 ns)
          product: HMAA1GS6CJR6N-XN
          vendor: Hynix
          physical id: 0
          serial: 22964AED
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0,3 ns)
          product: M471A1G44AB0-CWE
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you! I added the information you asked for.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i sdb /var/log/syslog*`. If this output is large, paste it at paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: @heynnema I added everything. There are no entries for sdb in syslog from the 21.07 though and it froze three times that day

Comment: I made a mistake on two of my commands... please show me `grep -i nvme /var/log/syslog*`. I'm already working on an answer for you. Thanks!

Comment: To check for a BIOS update, I need the exact model # for your laptop.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you so much! I dumped the response on paste.ubuntu.com, the link is in my edit.

Comment: @heynnema I have two numbers on the back
MO: MPNXB152007R and MTM: 21A20005GE

Comment: Syslog looks ok. BIOS looks ok. Do the firmware part of my answer. Report back.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory`. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema I added lshw -C memory to my Post. I also updated the firmware of the SSD and also did an extended SMART diagnostics test which resulted in no errors found.

Comment: Good job! Did both nmve's need a firmware update, or just the new one? See Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Only the second drive needed an update. The 13GB of RAM actually also suprised me initially, because win taskmgr is showing the same amount (https://pasteboard.co/KcwrFsy.png). I googled this the day I got the laptop and found this post: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/718566/16gb-ram-only-13gb-usable-but-cannot-change-maximum-memory-value/

Apperantly those 3GB seem to be allocated to the internal graphics card

I will do the memtest tomorrow and report back when I have the results! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'd be surprised if all 3G went to the internal video. The firmware update on the new nvme may have fixed your problem. If it does, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I'm on vacation, I'll do it when I find the time. Problem didn't appear again until now but I didn't use the laptop so extensively since the last time too. I'll make sure to flag your answer as correct, when I'm certain the problem is gone. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

Lenovo IdeaPad 14 G3 21A20005GE

You have BIOS version GQCN20WW(V1.06). You have the latest BIOS available.

**Firmware**

WDC PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101, S/N:210248804767, FW:21160001, 512 GB

WDC WDS500G2B0C-00PXH0, S/N:20360D443605, FW:211070WD, 500 GB

Download the `Western Digital Dashboard` from [here](https://support-en.wd.com/app/products/product-detail/p/1533#WD_downloads) and check the firmware for your WD NVME SSD's. Windows or FreeDOS (http://freedos.org) required.

**Update #1:**

`free -h` reports 13G RAM, which is an odd amount.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           13Gi       870Mi        12Gi        26Mi       582Mi        12Gi
Swap:         5,6Gi          0B       5,6Gi
```

`sudo lshw -C memory` reports 16G RAM installed (8G x 2).

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Note**: Make sure that memtest reports 16G RAM

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, since I updated the firmware of the SSD the problem hasn't appeared again

Answer (score 0):

After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.

Comment: Thank you! How can I check for overheating? Would that be a hardware problem? So far I didn't encounter any errors on windows, but I didn't use it for so long on windows yet either.